# Is Converting to Standard Form Necessary to Check if a Proposed Solution is a Basis in Linear Programming?

Tags: linear-programming

If I have a Lp problem should I make it to standard form and then calculate number of 0s in the proposed solution and compare it to :

number of equation - number of variables;

And that's for checking wether the solution is a basis(BFS) or not.

What I know is if I have a proposed solution (expressing the original variables) I can directly check weather it is a bfs or not without the need to convert it to standard form.

P.s: this step is just the 2nd step of checking

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/is-converting-to-standard-form-necessary-to-check-if-a-proposed-solution-is-a-ba

Comment: @RobPratt I don't understand if that's a bad thing in the platform or not. I thought I should ask it somewhere else so someone can answer. Thank you